# How do you handle live video streaming in Flash AS3?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, sockets, video-streaming

I've been dabbling with socket servers in Java and now I'm ready to get my feet wet with an idea I had.

I would like to use python for my socket server and obviously AS3 for my client.  I'm able to create a full chat using my own python socket server but I'm almost clueless what to do now that I want to add in LIVE video (want to make it a live video "chat").

I've found tutorials but they are for FMS and I can not afford that, also Red5 looked nice but couldn't find a live video tutorial off hand (plus I would have to switch to Red5 from my own socket server).

So if someone could even nudge me into some resources on the subject (the subject of live video without using FMS) that would be very helpful, Google is failing me right now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

some fms server alternatives... 
about their features, u need to check them out individually..

1. http://code.google.com/p/rtmplite/              - python
2. http://rtmpy.org                                - python
3. http://code.google.com/p/haxevideo/ - haxe : C++ etc
4. red5 - u already using it
5. http://www.wowzamedia.com/ - Java
6. http://www.themidnightcoders.com/products.html - .NET, Java
7. http://code.google.com/p/erlyvideo/ - Erlang
8. http://code.google.com/p/rubyizumi/ - Ruby
9. http://www.rtmpd.com/ - C++
10. http://wiki.gnashdev.org/Cygnal - C++
11. http://mammothserver.org/ - C++

Comment: Thanks mate!  looking them over now, great list.

Comment: me, personally using rtmplite - enough for my needs

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience on using Red5, but...

As I can remember, Red5 is designed such that, it can be used in the exactly same way as FMS...

So you can just swap the server parameters in as3 to switch back and fore between Red5 and FMS.

Correct me if I am wrong :P

Comment: If someone can confirm that then that would be a pretty darn good solution :P

Comment: I used red5 for a streaming video project last year.  It requires a decent amount of set-up, but works very well once it's up and running.  The examples will get you 90% of the way there, so there's not much of a learning curve, either.